# ¿Cómo enviar una imagen con la api de WhatsApp?

Tags: api, whatsapp

Para usar la *api.whatsapp.com* .

En javascript tengo la siguiente línea que funciona correctamente

```
 window.open('https://api.whatsapp.com/send/?phone=51987654321&text=Hola&source=&data=';
```

Dado que tengo una imagen:

```
 imagen = 'C:/demo.png';
```

Deseaba enviar dicha imagen pero no encuentro con que parámetro se puede hacer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

así no hay como...
deberías crear un scrappe para poder simular un bots y te haga eso.

la otra opción es que utilices una librería de WhatsApp que hay algunas subidas a la web.

y en todas debes utilizar nodesJs que es sencillo de usar

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Para enviar mensajes de medios como los que expones ,solo los puedes hacer a través de las soluciones empresariales que ofrece WhatsApp a través de Meta ,esto son :

La API Cloud de WhatsApp con la cual a través de peticiones post puedes enviar los mensajes que necesitas.

Esta es la documentacion por si te interesa saber mas sobre el proceso, puedes crear una cuenta gratuita y comenzar a hacer pruebas.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/cloud-api/get-started

Comment: Si bien este enlace puede responder a la pregunta, es mejor incluir las partes esenciales de la respuesta aquí y proporcionar el enlace como referencia.  Las respuestas que son únicamente un enlace pueden dejar de ser válidas si la página vinculada cambia. - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/394773)